# Htaccess to only access for subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, cross-domain, subdomain

I would like to only let people view my subdomains not the original domain. And I only want the original domain to be viewed by me (I mean my IP).

```
hello.example.com -> view by anyone
example.com -> only view by me
```

is there any script that I can use for htaccess ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a htaccess file on your main domain and write the following in it:

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.45.67.89
```

Use your IP in the above code.

Comment: If I use this it will deny access to my subdomain too! I want the subdomain to be viewed by anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can do a permanant redirection to hello.example.com. This will make sure everyone visit your site under hello.example.com. This would be more appropriate for your users.

```
  RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
 RewriteRule ^hello/(.*)$ http://hello.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

If you really want to show a 403 Forbidden, you can do this

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
 RewriteRule ^hello/(.*)$ / [r=403,nc]
```

Comment: but how am I suppose to view example.com ? it will be redirected for me too .

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I added this code in htaccess located at **example.com**

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from MYIP
```

and this code to **hello.example.com**

```
order deny,allow
allow from all
```

I'm not sure if it's a proper way to do this, but it help me to block people from viewing example.com ( main domain ) but still let them to view the subdomain ( hello.example.com )